# Getting android.content.ActivityNotFoundException with Zxing

Tags: android, android-activity, barcode, zxing

I have followed the following tutorial : http://damianflannery.wordpress.com/2011/06/13/integrate-zxing-barcode-scanner-into-your-android-app-natively-using-eclipse/

But even after editing android manifest xml as told there I am getting the following error:

```
 android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN pkg=com.google.zxing.client.android (has extras) }
```

My Code :

```
 public class BarCodeScannerActivity extends Activity {  
        /** Called when the activity is first created. */  
        @Override  
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
            setContentView(R.layout.main);  


        Button ok;  

       ok=(Button) findViewById(R.id.b1);  
       ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()  
         {

           public void onClick(View v) {   
              // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
              System.out.println("Helllllllloooooooo");
              Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");  
            intent.putExtra("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN.SCAN_MODE","QR_CODE_MODE");       
                startActivityForResult(intent, 0);   

        }
    });
        }

     public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {             
    System.out.println("onActivityResult________resultCode________ "+resultCode);   

    if (requestCode == 0) {   
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {    
            String contents = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT"); 
            System.out.println("contentsssssssssssssssssssssss" + contents);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Congratulations!!!... Product Code"+ contents + "On Scanning This Item..." ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  

            String format = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT");   
            System.out.println("Formaattttttttttttttt " + format);
            // Handle successful scan      
        }   else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {   
            // Handle cancel       
          }    
      } 
  }
  }
```

And mainfest file:

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".BarCodeScannerActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>



    </activity>


    <activity android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="landscape"
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden">

    <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>


        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>





</application>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

Hi

Now i am getting a strange problem of attached screen shot once i updated my manifest as follows:

```
<activity android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity"  
              android:screenOrientation="landscape"  
              android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
              android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
             android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>  
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
  </intent-filter>
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
  </intent-filter>
  </activity>
![enter image description here][1]
<activity android:name=".ScanItemActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden">
        </activity>
```

I mean it says ""Sorry, the Android camera encountered a problem. You may need to 
restart the device."

Nothing is there in logcat.

Comment: Try inserting `<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
` block in the `BarCodeScannerActivity`

Comment: sorry i did not get you.. i have already added those things right?

Comment: Also try this: Remove `com.google.zxing.client.android` from `com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity`in the `<activity>` tag.

Comment: Yeah, but not in the `BarCodeScannerActivity`. You've added it in the second activity, that is `com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity`

Comment: Have you created the other activity? `com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity`?

Comment: no.. i did not create it.. Its the default activity right?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6997/discussion-between-ghost-and-sneha)

Answer (score 3):

This is quite confused. You don't need to change your manifest at all if you are integrating by Intent, so remove anything you changed just for the integration.

The app is not installed, and you are not handling this properly. You must catch `ActivityNotFoundException`, or determine ahead of time that the app to handle the `Intent` is installed.

But, there is no need for any of this complexity. See http://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/ScanningViaIntent . You can use `IntentIntegrator`, which does all of this for you correctly, in a few lines of code.

Comment: no.. i don't want to use the installed app. If you check the blog i referred, you will get it.

Comment: Yes, I wrote the code that blog is based on: I get it. You are mixing two unrelated things here. If you are trying to embed the decoder, you don't use Intents. But if you are new to this, I strongly suggest you use Intents, as I think it takes a fair bit of sophistication to build your own scanner app (that is, not copying and pasting our code).